# Group features from feature layer by specific field without making multiple queries

Tags: esri-leaflet

I have a feature layer where one of the properties always takes 4 possible values.

Now I want to make 1 request to get all the features, group them by this property and feed each group to a different [markercluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) (or [esri leaflet cluster](https://github.com/Esri/esri-leaflet-cluster)) so I can have a separate cluster for every group. However it doesn't seem possible to do it without creating a cluster layer for each group explicitly, which would result in 4 separate requests and multiplying complexity. As far as I can see `pointToLayer` and `iconCreateFunction` doesn't really do the job (and they do weird things when points are removed or recreated), and panes only group the rendered markers, not the actual cluster itself.

Answer (score 0):

`marker.cluster` clusters need names, you would have to declare each one separately.
You can however query your full layer once hold the GeoJSON object under the name data and use [leaflet's `filter` method](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#geojson-filter)

```
var data;
fetch('url://of.the.esri.featureserver.query', {
  method: 'GET'
}).then(function(response) {
  data = response.json();
})

var cluster1 = L.markerClusterGroup();  
var cluster2 = L.markerClusterGroup();  

var layer1 = L.geoJSON(data, {
  filter: function(feature){
    if(feature.properties.column == 1 ){
        return true
      }
}
});

var layer2 = L.geoJSON(data, {
  filter: function(feature){
    if(feature.properties.column == 2 ){
        return true
      }
}
});

layer1.addTo(cluster1);
layer2.addTo(cluster2);
```

This way you get the data once, and use it multiple times.

Comment: This would always return *all* the features in the feature layer, no? My feature layer contains lots of points and I really need to confine the return result within the boundaries of the map, so getting all of them at once is out of the question. Manually re-inventing the code for this and updating the data dynamically would be a really big hassle...

Comment: You would have to share some code if you want to explain what is your problem. I would also recommend asking what is your input if possible and what is your desired output.

Comment: I don't see how any of that would help explaining the problem. I already have a feature layer that I'm using `L.esri.featureLayer`/`L.esri.Cluster.featureLayer` to integrate with and display. Now I want to group the points into several categories to feed into each layer of its own. I **DO NOT** want to re-invent the wheel and re-implement all the features `featureLayer` gives to me, including bounding box, query, max/min view and other things by fetching the features manually.

Comment: Then why not use the query option as documented [here](https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/api-reference/tasks/query.html)?

Comment: I want to avoid making 4 requests separately. Each group of points would then be rendered at different times and it's difficult to coordinate them together.

Comment: Then you can use query to get your layer as a featurecollection and use that with the `filter` option.

Comment: As I already said, I don't want to pull all of my features at once. As a SQL query it would be something like `select * from MyFeature where ... group by myProperty ...`. I want to narrow down the data queried back by the `where` clause before the `group by`, and I want to use `group by` instead of making one query per possible value.